# How to automatically set autoscroll on bluetooth mouse in Linux

Tags: mouse, linux-mint, bluetooth, scrolling, x-server

I'm running Linux Mint 20.3 and I created a .xsessionrc file to set autoscroll settings on all connected mice. However, I am using a Logitech M590 bluetooth mouse which connects too late to be configured by that file in the startup sequence. What can I do to get it to configure autoscroll automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by too late? Do you connect the mouse manually or does it get connected automatically?

Comment: It connects automatically shortly after the gui starts. Autoscroll works on startup with a wired mouse, but with a bluetooth mouse I have to enable it manually.